# HEAD request vs. GET request

Tags: python, http, urllib2, head, pycurl

I always had the idea that doing a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` request was faster (no matter the size of the resource) and therefore had it advantages in certain solutions.

However, while making a `HEAD` request in Python (to a 5+ MB dynamic generated resource) I realized that it took the same time as making a `GET` request (almost 27 seconds instead of the 'less than 2 seconds' I was hoping for).

Used some urllib2 solutions to make a `HEAD` request found here and even used `pycurl` (setting `headers` and `nobody` to `True`). Both of them took the same time.

Am I missing something conceptually? is it possible, using Python, to do a 'quick' `HEAD` request?

Comment: As an addition to the notes below, some servers *do* respond faster to HEAD requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server is taking the bulk of the time, not your requester or the network. If it's a dynamic resource, it's likely that the server doesn't know all the header information - in particular, Content-Length - until it's built it. So it has to build the whole thing whether you're doing HEAD or GET.

Answer (score 1):

The response time is dominated by the server, not by your request.   The HEAD request returns less data (just the headers) so conceptually it should be faster, but in practice, many static resources are cached so there is almost no measureable difference (just the time for the additional packets to come down the wire).

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, the bulk of that request time is actually whatever process generates the 5+MB response on the server rather than the time to transfer it to you.

In many cases, a web application will still execute the full script when responding to a HEAD request--it just won't send the full body back to the requester.

If you have access to the code that is processing that request, you may be able to add a condition in there to make it handle the request differently depending on the the method, which could speed it up dramatically.